# Breaking JQM ControlGroup when dynamically adding collapsible to set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using the HTML5 `<template>` tag to define a collapsible item to be added to a collapsible set.  The definition contains a button controlgroup which becomes broken apart when added.

```
HTML
  <template id="template">
    <div data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false' data-collapsed-icon='carat-d' data-expanded-icon='carat-u' id='pListItem'>
      <h3 id='pDesc'>Item 2</h3>
      <div class='w3-row'>
        <div class='w3-col s5 m5 l5'>
          <img id='pImg' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Army_Combat_Boot_(Hot).jpg' style='max-width:100%;max-height:150px;'>
        </div>
        <div class='w3-col s7 m7 l7'>
          <div style='text-align:right'>
            <p id='pNowPrice' style='font-size:24px;margin:5px 0px;'>$199.99</p>
            <p id='pWasPrice' style='font-size:12px;margin:0px 0px;'>$299.99</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='w3-col s7 m7 l7'>
          <div style='font-size:12px;text-align:right;'>
            <p id='pUPC'>UPC: 999999999999</p>

            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="buttonGroup2">
              <a href="#" id="pAddButton" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-left">Add</a>
              <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-right">Info</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

JS
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {
  var content = document.querySelector('#template').content;
  document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
  $('#container').collapsibleset('refresh');
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue.  Item 1 is defined in HTML and displays correctly.  Item 2 gets added using a template and shows the broken control group.
https://jsfiddle.net/PolishVendetta/v2uc64yk/

Adding a controlgroup refresh throws an error

"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on controlgroup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of refreshing the collapsibleset, tell jQM to enhanceWithin():

```
$('#container').enhanceWithin();
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/v2uc64yk/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I assume if I attach this to a button it will work multiple times?

Comment: @PolishVendetta, yes, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/v2uc64yk/2/

Comment: Just for my knowledge, how did you know to use .enhanceWithin() opposed to .collapsibleset('refresh')

Comment: @PolishVendetta: http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/  enhanceWithin enhances all children whereas refresh is meant for the widget it is called on.